# Laravel: unable to update or install any thing via composer

Tags: laravel, installation, composer-php, package

I am trying to install the Form & Html package in the laravel v5.8.4 via composer but its not working. I am getting this error every time. I tried googling the solution but all failed. Always the same error.

I am trying to install `"laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"`. Tried both ways, `composer update` and `composer require ...`

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.8.4
- graham-campbell/htmlmin v4.4.0 requires illuminate/view 5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4].
- graham-campbell/htmlmin v4.5.0 requires illuminate/view 5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
- don't install illuminate/view 5.2.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.2.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.2.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.2.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.2.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.2.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.2.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.2.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.2.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.2.32|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.2.37|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.2.43|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.2.45|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view 5.3.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.3.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.3.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.3.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view 5.4.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.4.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.4.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.1.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.1.41|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- don't install illuminate/view v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- Installation request for laravel/framework 5.8.4 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.4].
- Installation request for graham-campbell/htmlmin ^4.4 -> satisfiable by graham-campbell/htmlmin[v4.4.0, v4.5.0].
```

Comment: Try: composer require cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable:4.1.*

Comment: @lexjwa still no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revert back your `composer.json` and `composer.lock` file

After try
`composer require laravelcollective/html`

It will install the latest one and it is compatible with `laravel 5.8`

You are trying to install `"laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"` with a particular tag which is not compatible with `laravel 5.8`

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check with your laravelcollective/html": "~5.0" package, whether it supports Laravel 5.8. If any of your package doesn't match laravel 5.8 version, this error will be shown. Add appropriate version and run composer update. It will definitely work...